# CPU Governor Not 'Idling' After Kernel Update

Tags: 14.04, kernel, power-management, intel

Last night, my laptop running Ubuntu 14.04 asked to update the kernel to 3.16.0-43. I noticed this morning that Conky is now reporting that my CPU is running around max all the time now.

Before installing this kernel update, my idle would be .8GHz. Now I'm lucky if I see anything below 1.4GHz. Needless to say, this is having a severe negative impact on battery life. I have the latest version of TLP installed, but it doesn't seem to be working as effectively.

F.Y.I., my CPU is an i3 3217U.

Comment: Please add to your question the outputs from `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` and `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor`. What was your previous kernel version? and does using it again result in lower idle frequency?

Comment: The output from `cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_driver` was the following:
`intel_pstate`
`intel_pstate`
`intel_pstate`
`intel_pstate`
The output from`cat /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor` was the following:
`powersave`
`powersave`
`powersave`
`powersave`

Edit: I hate how the comments deal with linebreaks. Previous version was 3.16.0-41. I haven't had a chance to boot into it and see if it fixes it.

Comment: When checking what my previous version was, I noticed I had several. So I went to clear them out. I was a little overzealous, and accidentally deleted ALL of them. Once I broke my install to where it wouldn't boot, I started up the live USB and reinstalled 3.16.0-43 generic and 3.16.0-41, but missed the timing to get into grub. So I booted into 43. Now it works like a charm, which is weird because I had rebooted a couple of times, and nothing had worked. It seems to be working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When checking what my previous version was, I noticed I had several kernel versions. So I went to clear them out. I was a little overzealous, and accidentally deleted ALL of them. Once I broke my install to where it wouldn't boot, I started up the live USB and reinstalled 3.16.0-43 generic and 3.16.0-41, but missed the timing to get into grub. So I booted into 43. Now it works like a charm, which is weird because I had rebooted a couple of times, and nothing had worked. It seems to be working fine now.